# Return the first and last value from one column when value from another column changes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a PostgreSQL query to return the first and last dates corresponding to indices. I have a table:

| Datetime | Index |
| --- | --- |
| March 1 2021 | 0 |
| March 2 2021 | 0 |
| March 3 2021 | 0 |
| March 4 2021 | 1 |
| March 5 2021 | 1 |
| March 6 2021 | 2 |

In this case, I would want to return:
[image]

I am wondering how I would write the PostgreSQL query for this.

Comment: What is the data type of `Datetime`?

Comment: `datetime` is of type `timestamp`.  `Index` is of type `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done with the following:

```
SELECT MIN("Datetime") AS Start
     , MAX("Datetime") AS End
     , "Index"
  FROM <your_table>
 GROUP BY "Index"
 ORDER BY "Index"
;
```